# Minecraft really strange chunk loading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For the past 4 days, the chunks in my minecraft has been messing up a whole lot.
No chunks load automatically and some chunks doesn't load at all.
Some chunks load when i place a block inside or right beside that chunk.

I've tried everything, including reinstalling the whole game, nothing has worked.
Please help

Comment: Which version? Chunk loading is weird in 1.13 and 1.14. Does the same problem occur in 1.12.2? Also, is it just one world or does the same happen in a newly generated world?

Comment: Smells like hardware (memory) issues. Have you checked your disk for errors?

Comment: as Fabian said, chunk loading has been bugged since the release of 1.13.